# Do you need to have had a Covid vaccine within the last 9 months to go to Spain?

Tags: covid-19, spain, event-based-effects, vaccinations

Recently, I’ve heard that you need to have had a Covid vaccine within the last 9 months to get into Spain.

Is this true? If you leave Spain and haven’t had a Covid vaccine in the last 9 months, can you get back in?

Comment: Welcome to the vaccination sudoku. Some weeks ago you didn't need it (I know because a familiar came) but probably the rules have changed in these weeks... who knows..

Comment: From February, the vaccination certificate is valid only for 9 months, in entire EU, but other methods may be available (like tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look it up on https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/ESP/7001 and https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> Spain.

From https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php:

> 2. Passengers must have:
>
> - a negative COVID-19 rapid antigen test taken at most 48 hours before arrival. The test result must be in English, French, German, Spanish or accompanied by a certified Spanish translation; or
> - a negative COVID-19 NAAT test taken at most 72 hours before arrival. Tests accepted are: CRISPR, HAD, LAMP, NEAR, PCR, RT-LAMP, RT-PCR, SDA and TMA. The test result must be in English, French, German, Spanish or accompanied by a certified Spanish translation; or
> - until 31 January 2022,  a COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that they were fully vaccinated with AstraZeneca (SK Bioscience), AstraZeneca (Vaxzevria), Covaxin, Covishield, Covovax, Janssen, Moderna (Spikevax), Nuvaxovid (Novavax), Pfizer-BioNTech (Comirnaty), Sinopharm or Sinovac at least 14 days before arrival; or
> - from 1 February 2022, a COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that they were fully vaccinated with AstraZeneca (SK Bioscience), AstraZeneca (Vaxzevria), Covaxin, Covishield, Covovax, Janssen, Moderna (Spikevax), Nuvaxovid (Novavax), Pfizer-BioNTech (Comirnaty), Sinopharm or Sinovac **at most 270 days** and at least 14 days before arrival; or
> - from 1 February 2022, a COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that they received a booster dose; or
> - a COVID-19 recovery certificate issued at least 11 days after the positive COVID-19 NAAT test result. The sample for the certificate must have been taken at most 180 days before arrival.
> - This does not apply to:
> - passengers younger than 12 years;
> - passengers arriving from Chile, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Hong Kong (SAR China), Indonesia, Korea (Rep.), Macao (SAR China), New Zealand, Rwanda or Saudi Arabia;
> - residents of the United Kingdom arriving from the United Kingdom;
> - deadheading crew.

Comment: I hope this changes, injecting myself continuously just for tourism sounds wrong and creepy